# i am getting this error from g++ compiler - invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

My complete program is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int max(int *,int); 

int main()
{
    int n, a[10], b;
    cout << "Please enter the no. of integers you wish to enter ";
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "please enter the " << i+1 << " no. ";
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    b = max(&a[0], n);
    cout << endl << "The greates no. is " << a[b] << " and its index position is " << b;
    return 0;
}

int max(int * ptr,int n)
{
    int b[10], i, max, k;
    &b[0] = ptr;
    max = b[0];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (max < b[i]);
        max = b[i];
        k = i;
    }
    return k;
}
```

I want to pass pointer to the function and find the greatest number.
I'm not sure if passing an array counts as passing pointers.

Comment: I highly doubt this is working: `&b[0] = ptr;`

Comment: You've got a semicolon right after the `if` statement: `if (max < b[i]);`

Comment: rectified my mistake over there now getting lvalue required as left operand of assignment in &b[0]=ptr;

Comment: @user3426284 You are hurry. Read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int  max(int *,int);
int main()
{
    int n,a[10],b;
    cout<<"Please enter the no. of integers you wish to enter ";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"please enter the "<<i+1<<" no. ";
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    b=max(a,n);
    cout<<endl<<"The greates no. is "<<a[b]<<" and its index position is "<<b;
    return 0;
}

int max(int *a,int n)
{
    int i,max,k=0;
    //&b[0]=ptr;
    max=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(max<a[i])
            max=a[i];
        k=i;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Try this program .
It does not use `b[]` , which is actually unnecessary , just pass array `a` as parameter .

**CHANGES** :

> b=max(a,n);

```
int max(int *a,int n)
{
    int i,max,k=0; // INITIALIZE k !
    //&b[0]=ptr;
    max=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(max<a[i])
            max=a[i];
        k=i;
    }
    return k;
}
```

You should initialize `K` to `0` .

Comment: There's still the semicolon after the if statement.

Comment: i am assigning the value of i to k so is initializing k=0 really necessary btw thanks for the help

Comment: Do you know why i got this error lvalue required as left operand of assignment in &b[0]=ptr;

Comment: you can't use this , but can use ptr=&b[0];

Comment: @user3426284: this is because you cannot change the address of array , because it has a fixed address , when you initialize it .

Comment: @user3426284: you have marked another answer as accepted ! You can only mark one answer as accepted , which you did with mine .

Comment: didnt know about only one answer correct marking your answer worked thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to allocate memory for b[10], you just need a pointer here, instead of

```
int b[10];
```

Just declare a pointer and set its address to the starting element of the array passed by the function.

ie

```
int* b= ptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is invalid  You may not make assignment

```
&b[0] = ptr;
```

an such an assignment has no sense because it tries to change the address of array element b[0].

You need not to declare any additional array in the function.

Moreover your function has undefined beahviour in case then the first element is the maximum element of the array. In this case the function returns variable k that was not initialized.
Also after the if statement there is a semicolon

```
if (max < b[i]);
```

So this statement also has no sense.

The function can be written simpler

```
int max( const int * ptr, int n )
{
    int max_i = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( ptr[max_i] < ptr[i] ) max_i = i; 
    }

    return max_i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your expression to :

```
b=max(a,n);
```

You need not pass array via reference, they are automatically passed by reference.

also change:
`&b[0]=ptr;`  to   `b=ptr;`

 but for that initialize b as `int * b;`

or simply,
don't assign value of ptr to b, just directly work on ptr.